# How to Segment Accelerometer Signal at idle points

Tags: java, graph, arduino, accelerometer, image-segmentation

I'm using an 3 axis Accelerometer(GY-521) to get the acceleration data and also the gyroscope to get the gyro data. I want to segment the signals at the idle points so that i can get the segmented signal at the idle points.

[image]

Is there any algorithm or example code that i could use to segment this kind of signal?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.